# Find the 5 most popular values mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database column called 'country_name' where it takes the country names of my shop buyers. How can i get the 5 most popular country names order by the frequency of appearing in my db? MOST POPULAR for me is how often that country names appears in my database. for example if i have the countries below:

```
Brazil
Nigeria
Nigeria
Chile
Chile
Chile
Norway
Italy
```

i want to get 1.Chile (cause it appears 3 times), 2.Nigeria (2 times), 3.Norway (1 time), 4.Italy, 5.Brazil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code:

```
SELECT country_name, count(*) as entries
FROM table
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY entries DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: thanks, that works...how can i echo in php that variables? i have a while($country = $get_country->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){echo $country['country_name']; } but i want to echo in different point into my code..not all together..can i use it somewhere like array? thanks